# Unrecognized database format'C:\.....\Employees.accdb for Microsoft Access Database File?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to access a file stored in a Microsoft Access database. (I am working in Visual Studio 2012)  I chose the Database source type, and the Dataset database model, when it asks me "which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?", I clicked New Connection, then I chose Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB).  Under the Database file name, I clicked browse and selected the appropriate file(Employees.accdb).  When I press Test Connection or Ok I get this error:  **Unrecognized database format' C:.....\Employees.accdb**.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show your connection string....

Comment: im sorry completely new to database stuff, how do i do that?

Comment: if it helps the file is on my computer

Comment: The problem is probably due to an incorrect OleDb driver selected by the wizard that builds your connection string. (The string used to connect to your database)

Comment: Right click your connection in the Server Explorer, choose Modify Connection, Click Advanced, look at the line Provider. You should have `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` as provider not `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` (the latter cannot recognize database in ACCDB format)

Comment: Ok i finally found it, now how do you get it to change to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?  it does not let me modify it.  Mabe i need to download it?

Comment: show your code and values!

Comment: Yoop, it work for me. Thanks @Steve

Comment: @Steve Thanks. This looks exactly like my problem. Do you know how I can change to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 which is the only one I can choose in Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure about that but if you build a 32 bit application I think you get only the compatible providers. If you have ACE for 64bit there is no point to show it for a 32bit application.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your computer is missing `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

You can get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but if anyone else has the same problem, this worked for me.

According to your description, I create a sample VB project and try connect to the Access 2016 database and I get the same result with you. Then I try to connect old version of Access database and it is successful.

I find the Provider that used to connect the old version is Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. But for Access 2016 database, we should use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. So we need to install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=23734), which will help us install and register Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to our local machine.

Then please connect the Access 2016 database with following steps.

Add New Data Source --> database --> Dataset --> New Connection --> Microsoft Access Database File --> select the accdb file -> Click Advanced button to change the Provider. Then click the OK button back to the Add connection windows and Test connection, it will succeed.
[image: Screenshot]