# ODBC: Unrecognized Database Format Access 2013 With Service Packs Updated

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc

I have tried to create a ODBC Connection using my MS Access Database Data Source which includes (*.mdb;*.accdb)

Using Access/Excel 2013 Windows 7 32bit

My database is .accdb format.

When I click OK I get the following error.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corrupted Access .accdb file: "Unrecognized Database Format"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884080/corrupted-access-accdb-file-unrecognized-database-format)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized database format'C:\…\Employees.accdb for Microsoft Access Database File?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23160313/11683)